# Как частично отпарсить или получить тело ответа, пока он загружается?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, response

**Использую kotlin flows и retrofit.**
Пытаюсь в процессе загрузки массива Json взять из него уже загруженные данные, чтобы не ждать, пока получу их полностью. Т. е. загрузилась **часть** ответа - отпарсил, потом вторая - снова отпарсил и так до тех пор, пока полностью не загрузятся данные.

Как происходит сейчас: загружается **полностью** ответ, потом только парсится, что занимает много времни.

Как можно указанными выше средствами добиться нужного результата?

Если ими нельзя, то какими можно?